# Javascript private method dedicated caller returns undefined

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to defined a method `_` so that I can call my private method defined in my prototype, like http://webreflection.blogspot.hk/2008/04/natural-javascript-private-methods.html

My function are huge so I just pick a piece of case here

```
XXXXX.prototype = (function(){

    var  privateMethod =function() {
       return "success";
    }

    //public method here
    return { //returns a prototyp
        constructor: XXXXX,

        pubMethod: function() {
            console.log("normal call",privateMethod.apply(this));//success
            console.log("_ call",this._(privateMethod)());//undefined
        },

        //private method dedicated caller
        _: function(fun) {
            var that = this;
            return function() {
                fun.apply(that, arguments);
            }
        }
    };
})()
```

### Problem:

Why my `_` is not working as expected?where am I wrong?

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: i think it's not a good idea to overwrite prototype, this may cause a lot of problems. Also your constructor should give you an error, the XXXXX function is still undefined when you assign it. maybe it's  better to have a more clear idea on how prototypes works

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, never seen an inplementation like this to do what you are trying to do, dont mind. I'll give an eye on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `return` on the `fun.apply`

```
function XXXXX(){}
XXXXX.prototype = (function(){    
    var  buildDimWhere =function() { return this.subject; }    
    return { 
        constructor: XXXXX,    
        pubMethod: function() {
            console.log(buildDimWhere.apply(this)) 
            console.log(this._(buildDimWhere)()) 
        },
        _: function(fun) {
            var that = this;
            return function() {
                return fun.apply(that, arguments); // <--- HERE!
            }
        }
    };
})()

// test code:
y = new XXXXX();
y.subject = '123'
y.pubMethod();
```

Without `return` it gives:

```
{ subject: '123' }
123
{ subject: '123' }
undefined
```

After adding `return` (see `<-- HERE!` part), the output:

```
{ subject: '123' }
123
{ subject: '123' }
123
```